# Unable to insert Varchar2 data using stored procedure with Table type as IN parameter

Tags: oracle, jdbc

We have used the following to create user defined types in Oracle database. The first one is a record type (similar to a row) and second is Table type constructed using the record type.

```
create or replace type REC_TYPE as object(bid number, bdesc varchar2(100));
/ 
create or replace type TAB_TYPE as table of REC_TYPE;
/
```

The following describes the table and procedure used to insert data to the table.

```
create table BOM (bom_id number, bom_desc varchar2(100));
/
create or replace procedure pBOM (tIn IN TAB_TYPE, res OUT VARCHAR2)
is
begin
  for i in 1..tIn.count loop
      insert into BOM values(tIn(i).bid, tIn(i).bdesc);
  end loop;
end; 
/
```

Here is the java code used to call the procedure using JDBC.

```
public  void method()   throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("<jdbc_url>", "<user>", "<password>")) {   


            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            Object[] attributes = new Object[]{1, "test bom"};
            Struct rec= connection.createStruct("REC_TYPE", attributes);
            Struct[] tab =  new Struct[]{ rec };
            Array tabArr = ((OracleConnection)connection).createOracleArray("TAB_TYPE", tab);

            CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call pBOM(?,?)}");
            cs.setObject(1, tabArr);
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.executeUpdate();

            connection.commit();
            tabArr.free();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

With the above, finally when we run the main method in java, it inserts the ID, but surprisingly not the description.

[image]

NOTE: The above sample code snippets are taken to explain the problem. There might be some minor issues in syntax, however it exactly replicates the issue we are facing in project.

Comment: There might be some fundamental issues which we are unable to find. Any insights or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your Java code and query result as text, [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Why can't you copy text from the remote desktop?

Comment: Recreating your code, it seems to work just fine, with Oracle 11gR2 and JDK1.7. (Had to change the object field name from desc to descr to avoid the reserved word, but otherwise I believe it's identical; noticed you aren't closing `cs` or `connection` but not relevant to the issue). Maybe you have a JDBC driver/database mismatch that's causing odd behaviour? Otherwise, create [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for responding. Will try to update the post with code for Java also. Just to add more information, we are using jdk8u121, Oracle 12c rel 12.1.0.2.0 and ojdbc7.jar for jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't see any more answers, I thought to post the reason behind the issue. It was happening due to missing library in classpath which was orai18n.jar without which the text data was not getting updated to database.

So we need to add both the driver as well as language support Jars to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes from your code - using `oracle.sql.ARRAY` rather than `java.sql.Array` and then using `OracleConnection.setARRAYAtName()` rather than `Connection.setObject()` to bind the parameter.

*(Note: this worked using Oracle Driver ojdbc6.jar with Oracle 11.2.0.1)*

**Oracle Setup**;

```
CREATE TYPE rec_type AS OBJECT( id NUMBER, descr VARCHAR2(100) );
/
CREATE TYPE tab_type AS TABLE OF rec_type;
/
CREATE TABLE bom OF rec_type;
/
CREATE PROCEDURE pBom( t IN tab_type )
IS
BEGIN
  FORALL i IN INDICES OF t
    INSERT INTO bom VALUES t(i);
END;
/
```

**Java**:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

public class TestDatabase2 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Connection con = null;
    try{
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

      con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
        "username",
        "password"
      );

      ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TAB_TYPE", con);

      Object[] o1 = { 1, "ABC" };
      Object[] o2 = { 3, "DEF" };
      Object[] o3 = { 2, "GHI" };

      ARRAY objs = new ARRAY( des, con, new Object[][]{ o1, o2, o3 } );

      CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{ call pBOM( :arr )}");

      ((OracleCallableStatement) st).setARRAYAtName( "arr", objs );

      st.execute();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
       try {
         if ( con != null )
         {
           con.close();
         }
       } catch ( SQLException e ){}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MT0. Initially we tried with `oracle.sql.ARRAY` in place of `java.sql.Array`. That was also not working for us. However as those classes are deprecated now, (ref: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ARRAY.html)  we replaced with `java.sql`classes. Still I can see few changes in approach in your code. Will try those and update.

Comment: From the page you've linked the code could be changed to `java.sql.Array objs = ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)con).createOracleArray( "TAB_TYPE", new Object[][]{ o1, o2, o3 } ) );` and then use `((OracleCallableStatement) st).setArrayAtName( "arr", objs );` ... however, I don't have an Oracle 12 instance to hand to try it against (and `createOracleArray` throws an "Unsupported Feature" exception in `ojdbc6`). But that is almost to the code that you are using.